# Is it safe to access 'this' pointer from the second father as first father's pointer

Tags: c++

I have to admit that it's hard to express the question. So I have example：

```cpp
class P1
{
public:
    P1(int num) : m_Num(num)
    {
    }

    int m_Num = 0;
};

class P2
{
public:
    P2(P1* ptr) { std::cout << ptr->m_Num << std::endl; }
};

class S : public P1, public P2
{
public:
    S(): P1(567), P2(this)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    S abc;
}
```

Actually you'll get the output like this:

> 567

But I'm not sure whether safe to use `ptr` in `P2` according to the standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's safe, at least in this case. The key thing to note is that the standard allows to provide derived class pointer where base class pointer is expected. In your code P2 is base and S is derived, passing S's pointer where P2's pointer is expected is absolutely legal.

This is related to polymorphism and supported by all OOP languages.

Comment: Is "this" is a regular pointer by himself or some kind of a &class link in the current standard of c++?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. @Yury

Comment: "this" it is r-value pointer to the current object. Is it &X or *X kind of pointer?